# How to fix Filterizr responsive gallery from stacking images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, gallery

I am currently using a jQuery library called [Filterizr](http://yiotis.net/filterizr/) to create an image gallery.

Everything works just fine besides one problem... Randomly, the gallery will stack each image on top of another within one row. Kind of like a deck of cards spread out.

Here is an image:

[image]

This only happens sometimes. Like resizing the screen and then refreshing the page. However it doesn't consistently happen.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having this same problem. Will keep an eye on this thread in case anyone posts a solution (and will post one myself if I find it)

Comment: I found out the issue. It's within one of the classes. I believe project. Remove it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are responsive and have an auto defined height, the images are not rendered at their final height until after the filterizr script loads.  See below from their FAQ:

"MY IMAGES APPEAR WITHOUT HEIGHT
If the height of your .filtr-item elements depends on images then you might have trouble, because their loading might be slow the height of your items might be messed up. To solve this issue you can either set the height of your images explicitly or perhaps make use of DeSandro's imagesLoaded script which is only 5kb!"